# 'pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: macros, pdftex, windows, line

I have been using Latex through Tex Live and TexStudio and every thing is working fine.

Now I want to use Windows command line (cmd) to compile my tex files.

I get this error:
'pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Is there a specific step I should take?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Search in the Windows search for environment variable, there the dialogue to change the user environment should  appear. There you can add the path to the binaries to the path variable.